# converting DD-MM-YYYY to time (unix)

Tags: php, date, time

Can anyone please tell me how I convert DD-MM-YYY (text) to TIME (unix) thought I'd say that I have this line at the top of all my pages, just in case it means a different code.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); //### Set the default timezone
```

Comment: please use the search function before asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d-m-y is a valid GNU format. Use

```
$timestamp = strtotime('1-1-2012');
```

If its already in SQL you can call the databases method of conversion. MySQL uses UNIX_TIMESTAMP that should accept a valid datetime type in SQL.

Answer (score 7):

You will need [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) as long as its DD-MM-YYYY or similar approved format.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$date = "01/06/2012";
list($month, $day, $year) = split('/', $date);
$timeStamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);

echo $timeStamp;
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_string = "24/12/2017";
echo strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $date_string)));
```